# Cartesian <-> a+bi conversion

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems

For the question in the image,

[Question and my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTIwM.png)

I answered this question with (1/root5, -1/root5), which correspond to x and y value in Cartesian coordinate.

However, the correct answer for this question says, 1/5-3i/5, as following picture:

[Correct answer for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQCx.png)

What I actually did is to convert that 1/5-3i/5 into x and y form using x=rcos(theta) and y=rsin(theta), becuz I thought x and y value represents Cartesian coordinate if it is about 2 dimensional.

So my question is, does that form of a+bi really represents Cartesian coordinate?

Comment: It looks like you wrote the answer in the first line directly under the question in a way that matches the other picture, but I don't understand what's going on in the rest of your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$a+bi\ $ represents coordinates in the complex plane, where $a$ is the real component, and $b$ is the complex component.

The [Cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) can be used to represent any complex number. Your answer was to be given in Cartesian coordinates.

Check [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Complex_numbers) out.

Comment: $a+bi$ **is** the so called cartesian form. He was given $\frac{x+yi}{a+bi}$ which is not.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thank you, corrected

Comment: There's something still wrong, what do you mean by "$r=\cos \theta$"? Writing a complex number in **polar coordinates** doesn't require the number to have norm $1$, and OP did not assume that anywhere.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You are right, this was a mistaken claim. I will remove that.